# Send newsletter using smtp server

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, newsletter, configuration, smtp

I setup magento to use a SMTP server account to send emails.

I used the `System->Configuration->Advanced->System->Mail Sending Settings` and overwrote `getMail()` from `app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Email/Template.php` as described [here](http://serversmtp.com/en/smtp-magento-settings).

```
public function getMail()   
      {
           if (is_null($this->_mail)) {               
               /* changes begin */      
             $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
             $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
             $config = array(
                       'port' => $my_smtp_port,                                              'auth' => 'login',                   
                       'username' => 'email@domain.com', 
                       'password' => 'yourpassword'                                               );
            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host, $config);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
            /* Changes End */
            $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
        }
        return $this->_mail;  
}
```

Now to the question: How do I send the newsletter using second smtp account (same mail server)?

I would like to use 2 accounts at the same time. One for newsletter and one for everything else like support, order, ...

Comment: Have you thought about just using Mailchimp? You won't have to worry about your server getting blacklisted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Configure Username + password**

As already done in your function above, you could create fields for your System Configuration to enter these details and request them in your function like this:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/smtp/user');
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/smtp/password');
Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/smtp/user');
Mage::getStoreConfig('newsletter/smtp/password');
```

etc.

**Use Newsetter, General, etc. data**

There is also a function `getMail()` in `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Template`. You could adapt this function for sending and using the Newsletter-SMTP data.

**E-Mail Account Segmentation**

If you need further segmentation of the e-mails sent, my idea is to depend this on the e-mail templates used so that you create an assigment `Template > Account`.

Answer (score 1):

for those to whom it dosn't  work the modification of the :

```
public function getMail()
```

You can try modifing the public function send()

adding after:

```
public function send($email, $name=null, array $variables = array())
    {
        if(!$this->isValidForSend()) {
            return false;
        }
```

the followinng code with your smtp server configurations

```
$config = array(
        'ssl' => 'ssl', //optional
        'port' => '25', //or other port
        'auth' => 'login', //auth type
        'username' => 'yourusername',
        'password' => 'password'
    );

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.yoursmtpserver.com', $config);
```

modify the the line:

```
$mail->send();
```

to

```
$mail->send($transport);
```

save and flush cache.

The host and port fields under System-> Email setting must be blank.